# List the pair of customers who share the same phone number

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

This is my table
**Customer (custid, custName, custAddress, custPhone)**

My Question is
**List the pair of customers who share the same phone number.**

I just created the following table:

[image: Table]

Comment: I'd assume they also want the the SQL query giving the desired result.

Comment: Riddle me this: How would you ask your mySQL server to list all customers who share the same phone number?

Comment: The question asks for pair (ie 2) no more no less who have the same number so that's what you need to test. And you should have an output of sam and sri

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's assume that all the phone numbers in your table are "spelled" the same way. For example, let's assume that `+1.212.555.1212` and `(212)555-1212` are different phone numbers, even though they, according to the North American Dialing Plan, reach the same telephone. Every country has similar alternative phone number "spellings".

Handling phone numbers in the real world is a giant hairball. [Read Falsehood Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md).  But, let's leave that aside.

You should start with a subquery to find all the numbers that appear more than once.  This is it

```sql
                 SELECT custPhone
                   FROM Customer
                  GROUP BY custPhone
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You're a student. You should strive to completely understand this subquery. Start by running it on your table. HeidiSQL is good for this kind of thing.

Then, use the subquery in a main query.

```sql
SELECT Customer.*
  FROM Customer
  JOIN (
                 SELECT custPhone
                   FROM Customer
                  GROUP BY custPhone
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) multiple ON Customer.custPhone = multiple.custPhone
 ORDER BY custPhone, custName
```

**Pro tip** Avoid mixed case in database, table, and column names. It reduces the portability of your data from one server to another.

Comment: now I am doing this

SELECT * FROM `Customer`
WHERE `Customer`.`custPhone` IN(
 SELECT `Customer`.`custPhone` FROM `Customer` group by `Customer`.`custPhone` having count(`Customer`.`custPhone`) > 1
)
order BY `Customer`.`custPhone`;

I think you need to set HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 instead of HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
otherwise it will print the number which exists only once

Comment: I should have written `COUNT(*) > 1`, not `>= 1`. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE custPhone IN(
    SELECT custPhone FROM Customer group by custPhone having count(custPhone) > 1
)
order BY custPhone;
```

Table Data
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6bj4.png)

Query Data
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDDlt.png)